# How to reverse the direction of colorbar in R plotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, colorbar, r-plotly

I use the R interface of `plotly` to draw with a colorbar, which maps a continuous variable to color gradients. By debault, the `plotly` puts the minimum value at the bottom and the maximum on the top of the   colorbar. An example is displayed in the figure.

[image: example colorbar]

Now I want to reverse the whole colorbar, with the minimum value on the top. However, I haven't found (or I have missed) an option to accomplish my goal. Is there any way to reverse the colorbar?

---

Thanks @vestland for providing the following example code:

```
library(plotly)
df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_us_ag_exports.csv")
df$hover <- with(df, paste(state, '<br>', "Beef", beef, "Dairy", dairy, "<br>",
                           "Fruits", total.fruits, "Veggies", total.veggies,
                           "<br>", "Wheat", wheat, "Corn", corn))
# give state boundaries a white border
l <- list(color = toRGB("white"), width = 2)
# specify some map projection/options
g <- list(
  scope = 'usa',
  projection = list(type = 'albers usa'),
  showlakes = TRUE,
  lakecolor = toRGB('white')
)

fig <- plot_geo(df, locationmode = 'USA-states', reversescale = T)
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(
    z = ~total.exports, text = ~hover, locations = ~code,
    color = ~total.exports, colors = 'Purples'
  )
fig <- fig %>% colorbar(title = "Millions USD")
fig <- fig %>% layout(
    title = '2011 US Agriculture Exports by State<br>(Hover for breakdown)',
    geo = g
  )

fig
```

The argument `reversescale` reverses the mapping between the value and the color. However, my goal is to reverse the whole colorbar (without changing the mapping). In my case, it is more reasonable to put value `1` on the top of the colorbar and the maximum at the bottom, as the values are the ranks of some indicator.

---

Similar problems for pure `ggplot`. I just found that I was unable to reverse the colorbar in `ggplot` either.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using `plot_geo()`. In that case just include `reversescale = T` like this:

```
plot_geo(df, locationmode = 'USA-states', reversescale = T)`
```

This should also be valid for most other functions using a colorbar.

#### Plot 1: `reversescale = F` or unspecified

[image]

#### Plot 2: `reversescale = T`

#### Complete code:

```
library(plotly)
df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_us_ag_exports.csv")
df$hover <- with(df, paste(state, '<br>', "Beef", beef, "Dairy", dairy, "<br>",
                           "Fruits", total.fruits, "Veggies", total.veggies,
                           "<br>", "Wheat", wheat, "Corn", corn))
# give state boundaries a white border
l <- list(color = toRGB("white"), width = 2)
# specify some map projection/options
g <- list(
  scope = 'usa',
  projection = list(type = 'albers usa'),
  showlakes = TRUE,
  lakecolor = toRGB('white')
)

fig <- plot_geo(df, locationmode = 'USA-states', reversescale = T)
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(
    z = ~total.exports, text = ~hover, locations = ~code,
    color = ~total.exports, colors = 'Purples'
  )
fig <- fig %>% colorbar(title = "Millions USD")
fig <- fig %>% layout(
    title = '2011 US Agriculture Exports by State<br>(Hover for breakdown)',
    geo = g
  )

fig
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the information. However, as I explained in the edited version, I would like to reverse the direction of the colorbar, rather than reverse the color mapping.

Comment: @MilesNanshan Ah.. I will take another look.